# How to solve signal sigabrt error in swift while reading json file from computer hard drive?

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have a json file in my computer. I am trying to read that by this code:

```
func ReadQuestion(){  
    let path = "/Users/bishnudas/Documents/ExamFiles/questions.json"  
    do {  
        let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .mappedIfSafe)  
        if(data.count != 0){  

            let jsonResult = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data)  
            self.exampage.ExamQuestion = data  
            self.exampage.showWindow(nil)  
            self.window?.close()  
        }  
    } catch {  
        print(error)  
    }  
}
```

After reading that json file i am sending the data to another window and trying to convert that data like this:

```
func LoadQuestionPaper(){  
    do{  
        let QSJS = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: ExamQuestion!, options:JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers) as! NSDictionary  //Getting error signal sigabrt here        

    }catch {  
        print(error)  
    }  
}
```

Error message in console:

> Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x7fffa16f0fd0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fffa16f32d0).
>   2019-01-21 13:39:50.214466+0530 Unox Student Console[2071:66993] Could not cast value of type '__NSArrayM' (0x7fffa16f0fd0) to 'NSDictionary' (0x7fffa16f32d0).
>   Printing description of QSJS:
>   (NSDictionary) QSJS =

My json file structure:

```
[{
    "id": 1,
    "type": "sub",
    "text": "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\uc1\\htmautsp\\deff2{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\\f2\\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\\colortbl\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}\\loch\\hich\\dbch\\pard\\plain\\ltrpar\\itap0{\\lang1033\\fs18\\f2\\cf0 \\cf0\\ql{\\fs24\\f0\\b {\\lang2057\\ltrch Short notes: Concept based (20 marks)}\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\qj\\par}\r\n{\\fs24\\f0\\b {\\ltrch }\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\qj\\par}\r\n{\\f2 {\\ltrch }\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\ql\\par}\r\n}\r\n}",
    "num_toans": 4,
    "total_marks": 20,
    "questions": [{
        "IsAnswered": null,
        "markedForReview": null,
        "id": 1,
        "marks": 5,
        "type": "etq",
        "q_text": "{\\rtf1\\ansi\\ansicpg1252\\uc1\\htmautsp\\deff2{\\fonttbl{\\f0\\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\\f2\\fcharset0 Segoe UI;}}{\\colortbl\\red0\\green0\\blue0;\\red255\\green255\\blue255;}\\loch\\hich\\dbch\\pard\\plain\\ltrpar\\itap0{\\lang1033\\fs18\\f2\\cf0 \\cf0\\ql{\\fs24\\f0 {\\lang2057\\ltrch Why will ABC unit cost figures be different from TCA unit cost figures}{\\lang2057\\ltrch \\rdblquote }{\\lang2057\\ltrch ?}\\li0\\ri0\\sa0\\sb0\\fi0\\ql\\par}\r\n}\r\n}",
        "attachments": null,
        "choices": null,
        "tfq_ans": null,
        "blank_count": 0,
        "fitb_ans": null,
        "mcq_index": -1,
        "mcq_text": null,
        "excel_ans_attachment": "0",
        "word_ans_attachment": "0",
        "essay_ans_attachment": null,
        "subSections": null
    },
    ...
    ]
}]
```

Can anyone help me to solve this, or can suggest me the right way to convert that data into dictionary please?

Comment: `as! NSDictionary` this crashes since your data is an array not a dictionary.

Comment: Can you attach your json file structure? No need to attach the whole file, just the structure.

Comment: @Desdenova , can you suggest any solution for this ?

Comment: @pckill , I have attached the json format, sorry for the bad way of attaching the json, can you check it please.

Comment: Remove the `as! NSDictionary` and it should work. Here the returned object is of type `[Any]`.

Comment: @YannickLoriot, actually I want the data in dictionary format so that I can bind it to the NsOutlineView. Can you suggest me any idea about how I can bind that object to OutlineView UI.

Comment: Do you want to use the data as content of a `NSTreeController`?

Comment: Either you change your JSON format to return an object instead of a list of object or you just iterate over the returned list to build your objects: `QSJS.map(...)`

Comment: @Willeke, yes, I want to use the data in NSTreeController so that I can bind it to the NSOutlineView.

Comment: "The root content object of the tree can be a single object, or an array of objects." If `data` is an array of top level objects then set the content of the tree controller to `data`. If `data` is an array of one root dictionary then get the first element.